# how can i apply memoization to queryset methods as get, get_or_create

Tags: django, django-models, memoization

In my code I need cache some lookups like:

```
MyModel.objects.get(slug='foo')

MyModel.objects.get_or_create(slug='bar', defaults={'name':'bar'})
```

in order to avoid hits on DB.

I guees that applying memoization to these methods could be a good solution, but I don't find a correct way to implement this,

can you help me,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

These methods return the object for you, so you can cache it right away.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

a = cache.get('a')
if not a:
    a = MyModel.objects.get(slug='foo')
    cache.set('a', a)

b = cache.get('b')
if not b:
    b, exists = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(slug='bar', defaults={'name':'bar'})
    cache.set('b', b)
```

Hope I don't misunderstand your questions.